# Use of dynamic MDX Categories in Global Filters in the icCube application (dashboard)

Tags: iccube

**Situation**

I've defined a couple of MDX++ Categories in icCube and I want to use these as Global Filters in the application. An example of a MDX++ Categorie is

```
    create category member [Stats].[Top 100 Leveranciers].[Totaal].[top 100] as
       order(TopCount([leverancier].[leverancier].[leverancier],100, [measures].[bedrag]),[measures].[bedrag], bdesc),
       add_children=true
```

If I use this as a Global Filter in the application, all my dashboards are filtered, showing the data for the "Top 100 Leveranciers". Perfect, so far.

**Now comes the problem/ question**

Some users have a security setting that allows them to see only a subset of the data. The "Top 100 Leveranciers" should therefore be different to them, then to users that can view all the data. *But*, it is not. The "Top 100 Leveranciers" give exactly the same members for the persons with access to sub-set as to users that can access all.

--> *How can I achieve the desired functionality in icCube?*

**My analysis**

This is what I believe is happening 'under-the-hood':
To include a CATEGORY as a global filter option, it has to be defined in the SCHEMA DEFINITION as a SCRIPT. It is only allowed (so far) to have STATIC categories in the script. So I guess I am looking on ways to create CATEGORIES that can be used as global filters, but are DYNAMIC for dashboard users.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure to understand why the Top members are not filtered by the actual user access rights: should be the case. Better to contact icCube support directly.

Here is a quick details about STATIC vs DYNAMIC evaluation of the categories from the online [documentation](https://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/mdx/Create%20(Category).php):

```
    STATIC | DYNAMIC    : an optional modifier to specify the evaluation context. The default value is DYNAMIC:
                          in that case, when evaluating the formula the list of members is filtered by the slicer
                          and/or sub-select content. In STATIC mode, slicer and sub-select are ignored.
```